# Electric Shock off spinning motor

Tags: back-emf, shock

This large blower powering an inflatable structure has no on/off switch, requiring the actual power plug to be disconnected to power down the item. I frequently get a painful shock off the plug, and appreciate the back EMF off the motor or the still spinning action may be the cause.
I mean to wire a switch into the circuit, but I'm not sure if there are any steps I could take to deal with the voltage spike safely? could a light bulb or similar resistive load help? There is some aspect to back EMF that eludes me this many years after my electrical engineering course.

Comment: _”structure has no on/off switch, requiring the actual power plug to be disconnected to power down the item.”_ This does not sound legal. Call an electrician to install a switch for you.

Comment: "I frequently get a painful shock off the plug"... That indicates that the plug or cord or _something_ are wired incorrectly.  Yes, you need a switch, but you should rectify the other problems, too.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that you can be shocked by the prongs of the plug _after_ it has been completely pulled out from the outlet?

Comment: Please provide more details, such as the operating voltage, current, an frequency. Also, a few pictures would help tremendously.

Comment: I don't think the wiring is faulty, and indeed a new blower for a similar inflatable structure shows the same exact symptoms. Why the germans did not deem it necessary to wire in a switch is beyond me.

Comment: It's not a three phase. It's a normal 240v 50hz appliance. It arrived with a square pin plug, which was pretty awful for avoiding live. Now it has the 16a IP44 fitted it's not so bad. I don't think my friend will replace it, but I'm surprised it has no on/off switch, just for safety sake. The implication of the switch is what concerns me.

Comment: Yes, you can be shocked just holding the plug near the prongs, that's why I imagined it's a high voltage spike, thus my back emf burbling.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using theory-crafting about back EMF to dismiss or disregard a more serious problem.  And it's much more serious than a painful shock; the spectrum of harm goes far past "painful" and you've been lucky so far.

To start with, the ground pin is longer than the hot/neutral pins, and should disconnect last, so unless you're touching the hot/neutral prongs with your fingers, the shock is inexplicable *since the entire body of the plug is made of plastic*.  Obviously if you touch hot/neutral prongs while pulling out a socket, you're going to get a wallop, but don't handle plugs that way!

Any outdoor outlet or that serves outdoor loads should be RCD or GFCI protected. In North America, the 5mA GFCI is *per circuit* so it will be at the circuit breaker, a receptacle, or a prior receptacle on the circuit.

It could be that the cord or plug is damaged. This and the GFCI are maintenance issues, as well as the possibility that the ground pin isn't performing because it has (been) broken off. Some people are surprisingly luddite about grounds, especially if the intact ground results in GFCI trips, but breaking the ground makes the trips stop.

So I would start with using a 3-light+GFCI tester at the receptacle to validate that a) the ground wire back to the panel is bona-fide (and not bootlegged or missing), and b) the circuit is indeed GFCI protected (remember to disregard the light indications while pushing the GFCI test).  Then I would look closely at the plug for any defects, and promptly replace the plug if called for. There are a variety of field-installed plugs, some with quite large grip area to minimize hands slipping into the prongs.

I suspect your root problem here is one of the above defects or shortcuts.  I would focus on repairing those as these are lurking time bombs that can kill somebody, for real.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm unsure about the implications of the floating earth, but this device would do the same plugged into a domestic supply.  The plug/socket is a shrouded 16a industrial type though. The pins are accessible, but not overt. The issue is that when the motor is spinning down, there is a voltage on the pins that seems hard to avoid.  Assuming this isn't a fault, I wondered about the techniques used to manage this phenomenon in industrial equipment. Forty years ago, I did know how to do it, because I took an industrial electronics course. I just can't remember.